How to check if user logged in or no Laravel
This code in Laravel where I want to use it as API to show it for every one that visit my app. and I want to get user ID when he is logged in.
public function show($displayType)
{
    try {
        $data = houses::where('displayType', $displayType)->paginate(5);

        $user = auth()->user(); // Get the authenticated user

        $userId = $user ? $user->id : null; // Check if user is authenticated and get the user ID

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'You have successfully retrieved data',
            'data' => $data,
            'user_id' => $userId, // Include the user ID in the response
        ]);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $th->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }
}

I want to check if the person that visited my site is logged in or no.
But the problem is when I send token is return user id null
that's how use my route request.
// this my route I use it out the middleware check 
Route::get('houses/{displayType}',[housesController::class, 'show']);
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {})


Default usage
Use the check() function to verify if the user is logged in.
if (auth()->check()) {
  // User is logged in
  $user = auth()->user();
} else {
  // User is not logged in
}

In Blade, directives are also available for simplified invocation of these functions.
@auth
  // The data only available for auth user
@endauth

// and

@guest
  // Show content if unauthenticated
@endguest

We can explicitly specify that only logged-in users can access routes.
Route::get('houses/{displayType}', [HousesController::class, 'show'])
  ->middleware('auth'); // use middleware() function to add extra middleware to route

// or can use with group() function to can add extra middleware to more route

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
  Route::get('houses/{displayType}', [HousesController::class, 'show']);
})

Extra configurations for using another Auth Guard
Laravel by default applies web session-based authentication. If you want to deviate from this, you need to communicate it properly with Laravel through settings. If you want to use token-based API authentication for default login, you need to modify the defaults.guard value appropriately in config/auth.php as per the documentation.
return [
  'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api', // here
  ],
  'guards' => [
    // default guard
    'web' => [
      'driver' => 'session',
      'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    // can use this
    'api' => [
       'driver' => 'token',
       'provider' => 'users',
       'hash' => true,
    ],
  ],
];

If you prefer not to modify this, you have the option to override this value in each of your requests using the guard() function.
if (auth()->guard('api')->check()) {
  // User is logged in
  $user = auth()->guard('api')->user();
} else {
  // User is not logged in
}


But it still return userID null even I am doing the correct way to parse the variable

This means you're not logged in? What does the auth()->check() call output? Try placing this at the beginning of the function: dd(auth()->check());

Your question wasn't entirely clear, but if you're not using the default authentication, you need to switch the defaults.guard value in the config/auth.php file from web to api, for example. OR you can override this locally using auth()->guard('api'). Then, the check looks like this: auth()->guard('api')->check(), and querying looks like this: auth()->guard('api')->user().

I have asked chatGPT he told me change Kernal.php file
I am using Laravel 10x But I have no kernal in my project file
